# How to pass function parameter to an external function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

This is my function (of a react component class), which calls an apollo/graphQL mutation (`doSomething()`).

**example.js**

```
example (id) {
  const { elementID, doSomething } = this.props

  return doSomething({
    variables: { id },
    update: (proxy, { data: { getData } }) => {
      const data = proxy.readQuery({
        query: getDataQuery,
        variables: { elementID }
      })
      // ...do something...
      proxy.writeQuery({
        query: getDataQuery,
        variables: { elementID },
        data
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I need to get the update function in a separate file, but now I've lost the context for `elementID`:
As you can see the mutation call gets very readable as I put the update function in another file. But `elementID` is not defined anymore.

**example.js**

```
import { update } from './update.js'

example (id) {
  const { elementID, doSomething } = this.props

  return doSomething({
    variables: { id },
    update: update
}
```

**update.js**

```
export const update = (proxy, { data: { getData } }) => {
  const data = proxy.readQuery({
    query: getDataQuery,
    variables: { elementID } // <-- not defined
  })
  // ...do something...
  proxy.writeQuery({
    query: getDataQuery,
    variables: { elementID }, // <-- not defined
    data
  })
}
```

Comment: Try replacing update in example.js with update.bind(this) and replace elementID with elementID: this.props.elementID in update.js.

Comment: Please stop prefixing all of your titles with tags. We have tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**example.js**

```
import { update } from './update.js'

example (id) {
  const { elementID, doSomething } = this.props

  return doSomething({
    variables: { id },
    update: update(id, elementID) // <-- change this
}
```

**update.js**

```
export const update = (id, elementID) => { // <-- change this
  return (proxy, { data: { getData } }) => { // <-- change this
    const data = proxy.readQuery({
      query: getDataQuery,
      variables: { elementID }
    })
    // ...do something...
    proxy.writeQuery({
      query: getDataQuery,
      variables: { elementID },
      data
    })
  }
} // <-- change this
```

Comment: And if I would need the `id` parameter of the example() function also in the exported function? How can I pass this?

Comment: Unfortunately I do get `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` for the first implementation without using a closure. Although I bound `this` I don't get access to it. So I can't get `elementID`.

Comment: That surprises me. Try the new code I added just now. It uses only closures for both id and elementID.

Comment: With that I am loosing context for the parameter which are needed for the apollo client mutation (i.e. `proxy`). See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#api --> update

Comment: I don't see why that would be the case. Did you try it? Otherwise, I'd have to see the source code to help.